# Freeze only a specific row in Excel by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want freeze only a specific row using `vba`.

For example, if i freeze the row 10 all rows above until the row 10 will be freezed too. But i want freeze only the row 10. Is it possibile?

Also i don't want split the rows not even using selection.

My code that is that:

```
Sub Freeze()

ActiveSheet.Range("A11:A11").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't do this manually, and you can't do it with VBA either.

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze any range you want,
But you need to let Application.ScreenUpdating active while the sub is running.

The basic code to freeze the first row(you can change the rowstart and row end to change which rows to freeze):

```
Sub subFreezePane()
Dim RowStart As Long: RowStart = 1
Dim RowEnd   As Long:   RowEnd = 1
    With ActiveWindow
''|COMMENT: Unfreeze Panes|:
        .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitRow = 0
''|COMMENT: make upper part of the screen go to RowStart|:
        Application.Goto ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
        .SmallScroll down:=RowStart - 1
''|COMMENT: Freeze Panes|:
        .SplitRow = RowEnd - RowStart + 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
End Sub
```

To avoid some mistakes and have the possibility of freezing columns to:

```
Sub subFreezePane()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'|COMMENT:|CHOSE the RANGE of ROWS to Freeze(RowStart=0 Skips the rows freezing)
    Dim RowStart As Long: RowStart = 1
    Dim RowEnd   As Long:   RowEnd = 1
'|COMMENT:|CHOSE the RANGE of COLUMNS to Freeze(ColStart=0 Skips the columns freezing)
    Dim ColStart As Long: ColStart = 0
    Dim ColEnd   As Long:   ColEnd = 0
'
    With ActiveWindow
        If ((RowStart <> 0) And (RowEnd >= RowStart)) _
        Or ((ColStart <> 0) And (ColEnd >= ColStart)) Then
''|COMMENT:|Unfreeze Panes:
            .FreezePanes = False
            .SplitRow = 0
            .SplitColumn = 0
''|COMMENT:|Set up for Freezing:
            Application.Goto ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
            .SmallScroll down:=RowStart - 1
            .SmallScroll toright:=ColStart - 1
''|COMMENT:|Sets number of rows:
        If RowStart <> 0 Then
            .SplitRow = RowEnd - RowStart + 1
        End If
''|COMMENT:|Sets number of columns:
        If ColStart <> 0 Then
            .SplitColumn = ColEnd - ColStart + 1
        End If
''|COMMENT:|FREEZE  PANES
        .FreezePanes = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If there's something you don't understand, or you think might need some improvement give some feedback.